# Table storage for strings and booleans

Tags: java, android, arrays

I've implemented in-app-billing v3 and I'd like a way to keep some sort of table which contains 3 columns

(String) Name of product, (String) sku, (boolean) true/false

What is the best way to do this? The best way would (in my opinion) allow me to keep a static easily readable list of values where the first two were strings, the third a boolean. At the start all the values for the boolean column were false, but as I query purchases I am able to easily reset the value.

Just to add,

I'm against SQLite databases for the reason that they're just too easy to hack. I'd rather create it in code and thus I'm debating between an ArrayList within an arraylist or matrices or something like the following:

```
private static class CatalogEntry {
    public String sku;
    public String name;

    public CatalogEntry(String sku, String name) {
        this.sku = sku;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

private static final CatalogEntry[] CATALOG = new CatalogEntry[] {

new CatalogEntry("android.test.purchased", "Item1"),
        new CatalogEntry("android.test.canceled", "Item2"),
        new CatalogEntry("android.test.refunded", "Item3"),
        new CatalogEntry("android.test.item_unavailable", "Item4")

};
```

Is there a way to reset values in the CATALOG array if I add a third column, otherwise I'm considering using both that and standard arraylists.

Comment: This seems like quite a broad topic... I'd just keep an SQLite database with columns `INT id, VARCHAR name, VARCHAR sku, TINYINT purchased`, or similar. (Also remember that rooted devices would have access to this data.)

Comment: That's my worry with SQLite databases :/ I'd rather avoid using SQLite

Comment: Anything you store on the device is susceptible to tampering. Authorizing with a server is your best bet. Potentially using some kind of encryption on the local data would also work (AES'ing with a secure and unique key, for example; or maybe using something like BCrypt to hash the stored data for comparison later).

Comment: I'm going to look into both of those. Thank you. Sadly a server isn't a possibility for me :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sqlite with FOUR columns:

- sku
- name
- purchaseDate (or null if not purchased)
- md5Hash

When a purchase is made, you just concatenate the sku, name, purchaseDate, device-id, and a PSK, make an md5Hash and store it along with the other data in the row. When you check the contents of the table, you compare the md5 stored against the data, and you can verify whether the purchase was valid, or the table has been tampered with. You can even let the user back up the purchase table to sdcard (or use Android backup).